# How can I gradually make an element less opaque while I am dragging it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my program there are actually two suns, but one sun aka "dark_sun" is just behind the other aka "sun". I want "sun" to gradually fade out or gradually become less opaque halfway across the arc (which is the direction the sun is going in on my program), so only "dark_sun" will be visible by the end of the arc. How do I do that? This is the program URL: http://whatisupson.tumblr.com/

```
    <style>
        /* Colors */
        body {
             background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
             animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
             -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes mymove {
            0% { background-position: 0 0; }
            50% { background-position: 40% 0; }
        }
        #dark_sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 20%;
            left: 10%;
        }
        #sun {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 20%;
            left: 10%;
        }
    </style>

    <html>
    <body>
            <img id="dark_sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/f3UFHb7.png">
            <img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
    </body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var width = 300;
    var sun = $("#sun");
    var dark = $("#dark_sun")

    sun.draggable({
      axis: "x",
      containment: 'body',
      drag: function() {
        var x = sun.offset().left + (sun.width() / 2);
        var total = $(window).width();
        var heightPct = Math.pow((total / 2) - x, 2) / Math.pow($(window).width() / 2, 2);
        console.log(x, $(window).width(), heightPct * 100);
        this.style["margin-top"] = "" + Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";

        dark.css({
            left:x -(sun.width()/2),
            marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });
        $(this).css({
            marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
        });
      }
    });

    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try it like this, with a opacity relative to the borders of the window.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oujq3zpq/

```
    $(this).css({
        opacity: 1-(x/total),
        marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
    });
```

There is still room for improvement, because the sun never gets completely opaque with this method.

Comment: Thank you I think it is completely fine and it exactly what I wanted. Also say that I wanted to add a THIRD element such as a moon and wanted it to be visible in the last 1/3 of the arc. Can I just use the same method and it will work?

Comment: Yes that should work like that, just make your maths correct and it will work. If you need help you may ask again. You are welcome.

Comment: Yes, can you help me adjust the math? This is my new code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d1d6d2f2288f7336679

The moon is behind both suns right now.

Comment: Raw Version in here from there you should be able to work the rest out (smooth the change between moon and sun and so on) http://jsfiddle.net/m9dfa93h/

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a function to animate the "sun" css property opacity value from 0.0 to 1.0. Something like opacity=(distance from left/ window width)